Assignment to two different wires with a bit and its complement yields the same value
I am currently creating a control unit for a pipelined processor using Verilog. I'm using combinatorial assignment using wires. Since I have only limited instructions to support, I have decided to just assign control signals using only limited bits.
The following is the code for the main control unit:
module mcu(
    input [5:0] Opcode,
    output ALUSrc,
    output [1:0] ALUop,
    output RegDst,
    output MemWrite,
    output MemRead,
    output MemtoReg,
    output RegWrite
    );
    
    assign ALUSrc = (Opcode[0]);
    assign ALUop[0] = (!Opcode[0]);
    assign ALUop[1] = (!Opcode[5]);
    assign RegDst = (!Opcode[0]);
    assign MemWrite = (Opcode[3]);
    assign MemRead = (!Opcode[3]);
    assign MemtoReg = (!(Opcode[0]^Opcode[1]));
    assign RegWrite = (Opcode[5]^Opcode[3]);
    
endmodule

However the ALUSrc and RegDst yields the same value despite being complements.
Here is the testbench results for a sample test.
Thanks in advance for any answers.
I tried using both ! and ~, apart from which I have no clue how to fix. I've tried changing up the indexing as well, but to no avail.

Is that the only complementary pair that is wrong?

No, it's all of them. So I'm assuming it's something to do with my syntax? But I can't find anything wrong for the love of God.

I guess you could try ^,

That is for a two operator xor. If you're talking about replacement, the compiler will just throw an error.

I don't know Verilog from a hole in the ground, but I found syntax/operator document with examples of it used as a unary operator.

Ok, I'll give it a try!

Sorry, was my first question, will post a MRE next time!

The design issue reported in the post text, is not present in the posted code.
Here is a simple tb which drives a sequence 32'b0, 1, 2, 3 on Opcode
module tb ();
  reg [5:0] Opcode;
  reg ALUSrc;
  reg [1:0] ALUop;
  reg RegDst;
  reg MemWrite;
  reg MemRead;
  reg MemtoReg;
  reg RegWrite;
  integer i;
  
  mcu dut(
    .Opcode(Opcode),
    .ALUSrc(ALUSrc),
    .ALUop(ALUop),
    .RegDst(RegDst),
    .MemWrite(MemWrite),
    .MemRead(MemRead),
    .MemtoReg(MemtoReg),
    .RegWrite(RegWrite) 
    );
  
  initial begin
    // FOR EDA PLAYGROUND $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;
    $monitor("Opcode = %h, ALUSrc = %h RegDst = %h ",Opcode,ALUSrc,RegDst);
    
    for(i = 0; i < 4;i++)begin
      Opcode = i;
      #1;
    end
    
  end
endmodule

which produces the messages
xcelium> run
Opcode = 00, ALUSrc = 0 RegDst = 1 
Opcode = 01, ALUSrc = 1 RegDst = 0 
Opcode = 02, ALUSrc = 0 RegDst = 1 
Opcode = 03, ALUSrc = 1 RegDst = 0 

and these waves

using the posted code as the DUT.

The code is behaving as expected, something else is wrong.

Thank you for answering. It was an issue with the overall integration of the module. I should have added more context. Nonetheless thank you for the answer.
